# Selectable grid using React

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I currently have a grid with three columns. Where you can select one value at a time per column and it updates the selected value in a redux state.

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-elion-3e6oo?file=/src/styles.css)

My problem is if there was an initial value I need to set the grid to display/activate the necessary boxes in the grid. I have tried to put a

```
const gridState = useSelector(state => state.gridState);

useEffect(() => {
// Assuming I have my initial values in gridState
// Update selected boxes based on gridState
// This keeps on looping
}, [gridState])
```

But couldn't make it work.

Comment: Are you trying to update the same `gridState` inside `useEffect` ?

Comment: I have edited my question.  No I'm not updating gridState perse in useEffect, I am trying to update which boxes are selected based on the gridState.

Comment: Can you add the change in your sandbox so we can see the problem?